# AJAX no muestra mensaje en la función success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Cuando envió datos por AJAX a una pagina que procesa un update a la BD no me muestra un mensaje de éxito que coloco si se ejecuto correctamente la operación, cuando recupero la variable de la función success: function (variable)...

el codigo de mi ajax es el siguiente:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'procesaConfirmacion.vbhtml',
    data: $('#enviaConfirmacion').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#muestraFormulario").hide();
        cargando.show();
    },
    success: function (dataaaa) {
        cargando.hide();

        $('#resultado').hide().html(dataaaa).fadeIn(900);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No puedes invocar con el $.ajax un vbhtml de forma directa, tienes que hacer por medio de un action en un controller

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("NombreCtrl", "procesaConfirmacion")',
    data: $('#enviaConfirmacion').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function () {
        $("#muestraFormulario").hide();
        cargando.show();
    },
    success: function (dataaaa) {
        cargando.hide();

        $('#resultado').hide().html(dataaaa).fadeIn(900);
    }
});
```

veras que defino

```
@Url.Action("NombreCtrl", "procesaConfirmacion")
```

indicando la url al action que devolvera el render de la view `procesaConfirmacion.vbhtml`

en el controller defines

```
public class NombreController{

    public ActionResult procesaConfirmacion(){

        return View();
    }
}
```